# LED bulbs or LED downlight?

Tags: led, lighting

Correct me if I'm​ posting this in the wrong sub. I've never really played with LED lighting, but I've seen there are two types, bulbs and down lights. While the bulb type is more common as most of us still use CFL or already moved to LED, the down light type is somewhat interesting. It reminds me of the circular CFL. While I don't really see the advantage of using bulb against the down light version and vice versa, since from what I've seen they could have same wattage ratings (in this case I've seen both in 25W version). Are there any real advantage in between the two? Or is it just a mere design?

Comment: This question is probably better suited for the home-improvement page... but see my answer anyway.

Comment: Unlike other sorts, LED bulbs really don't like heat; long thin fixtures can be better for this than small compact ones. There's also the question of integrated transformer vs. separate one, e.g. IKEA light strips.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to diy.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DoxyLover it might be better to ask a moderator to move it than post that as a reason that its off topic. If you feel it should be moved then flag it and write a message to the moderator. Keep in mind that it needs to be on-topic on that site (some requests to move get rejected by the receiving site)

Answer (score 1):

Difference is in light footprint. Think of down-light like a spot-light.

LED Bubs are more intended to act more like.. well .. bulbs. That is, be non-directional. Down-lights will make a bright spot on your floor.

Generally the bulb type is more popular because people are trying to replace standard bulbs in standard fixtures.

However if you are replacing a bulb in say a pot-lamp, it makes more sense to use the down-light since you get more light coming in the direction you need for the same wattage.